# making a python gui for ffdshow

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ffdshow

I was thinking that for a learning project for myself, I would try to make a GUI for ffdshow on linux, using tkinter. Wanted to make sure this project would be feasible first, before I get halfway through and run into something that cant be done in python.

Basic idea is to have a single GUI window with a bunch of drop down boxes that have the various presets (like format or bitrate), as well as a text box where a custom number can be entered if applicable. Then when all the options are selected, the user hits the Start button on the GUI and it shows a progress little bar with a percentage. All the options selected would just send the relevant selections as cli arguments for ffdshow, and begin the conversion progress (essentially turning all the user's input into a single perfect cli command).

Is all this doable with python and tkinter? and is it something that a relative newb with only very basic tkinter experience could pull off with books and other python resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is precisely the type of thing that python and Tkinter excel at. And yes, a relative newbie can easily do a task like that.